# Is it harmful for the voice to raise the larynx on occasion by tensing the larynx elevator muscles?

Tags: technique, voice, voice-training

Is it bad in the long term to do this occasionally in order to achieve a certain timbre? It doesn't seem to cause strain on the vocal folds when I do this, as phonation remains resonant and effortless, apart from the necessary tension in the larynx elevator muscles and I can tune vocal fold closure and breath pressure, just as with a neutral larnyx.